Performance SOAPHandler handleMessage
I want to log all Request / Response data of a WS communication. I must do the logging (its more dumping the data into a RDBMS) asynchronous to not affect the performance of the WS communication itself.
My first idea was to just offer the SOAPMessageContext to a BlockingQueue I process in another thread. Unfortunately I noticed the message body in it became empty after the main thread consumed the Ws response (happens when com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Message.readPayloadAsJAXB() gets called during deserializing).
So I dropped that idea and changed my Handler code to use SOAPMessageContext.getMessage() instead. But well... this resulted in a huge performance drop for each webservice call, especially when big messages are being received.
I noticed that jaxws-rt has a Tube concept and I thought about using that to easily access the message - but I found no easy way to register my own Tube (I don't really want to provide own jaxws-tubes.xml).
So - I now ended up with a pretty bad solution:
I made "packet" in SOAPMessageContextImpl super class MessageUpdatableContext publicly accessible and call copy(true) on it. This copy is then handed to my BlockingQueue for further asynchronous processing.
The performance drop is quite low - even for big messages. But to be honest - is there a better solution? I guess there is a reason why Packet was made private the first place.
I am forced to use cxf generated Webservice clients and jaxws-rt.
public class LoggingSOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private final BlockingQueueHolder blockingQueueHandler;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggingSOAPHandler.class.getName());

    public LoggingSOAPHandler(final BlockingQueueHolder blockingQueueHandler) {
        this.blockingQueueHandler = blockingQueueHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            final Field f = context.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("packet");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            final Packet packet = (Packet) f.get(context);
            final Packet clonedPacket = packet.copy(true);

            if (!this.blockingQueueHandler
                    .offer(new SoapMessageContainer(Instant.now(), /* context.getMessage() */ null, clonedPacket,
                            Boolean.TRUE.equals(context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY))))) {
                // LOGGER.severe("Queue is full, Dropping SOAP Message...");
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
...



Looks like implementing a LogicalHandler instead of a SOAPHandler is doing the trick. handleMessage() then receives a LogicalMessageContext which has a fast getMessage(). The received message can still not be handled asynchronously because it becomes empty after the main thread received the WS response too, but directly calling .getPayload() on it during handleMessage() execution copies the message and returns a Source which can now be handled later asynchronously.
I also made some JMeter tests calling a REST-Endpoint 40,000 times (20 parallel threads) which then calls the WS-Endpoint using the xjc client - just to get an idea.
The WS-Endpoint itself returns a XML response 180k characters in size.
with no handler at all:

95th percentile: 22ms
median: 14ms
throughput: 300msg per sec

with LogicHandler and context.getMessage().getPayload()

95th percentile: 44ms
median: 20ms
throughput: 265msg per sec

with SOAPHandler and Reflection private access Packet

95th percentile: 44ms
median: 20ms
throughput: 264msg per sec

with SOAPHandler and context.getMessage()

95th percentile: 857ms
median: 112ms
throughput: 82msg per sec

